# Finding transformations that preserve lower moments

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider for simplicity a real-valued random variable $X$ with finite moments $m_X(n) = E[X^n]$, $n>0$. Now suppose we wish to construct a new random variable $Y = f(X)$, where $f$ is some measureable function such that the first $N$ moments are equal, e.g., $m_Y(n) = m_X(n)$ for $n \leq N$ for some fixed number $N$. Is there a standard procedure for finding such an $f$? Obviously such $Y$ is not unique, and it is even easy to establish existence of such $Y$ via moment generating functions or characteristic functions, but is there some sort of "natural" choice of $f$ that establishes equality of the lower moments in a simple way? Phrased in terms of, e.g., moment generating functions, this is equivalent to finding an $f$ such that $$\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \frac{d^n}{dt^n}\mathbb{E}[e^{tf(X)}],\,\text{for }n \leq N.$$

I am also interested in the general case of random vectors over $\mathbb{R}^n$, as the structure of, e.g, unitary transformations is richer in that context, but even the 1D case seems difficult.

Comment: You are misising an expectation in your equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick an arbitrary random variable $G$ with CDF $F_G(x)$ such that the first $N$ moments of $G$ are identical to that of $X$. Then you can simply pick $f = (F^{-1}_G\circ F_X)$. It is just a copula transform from $X$ to $G$ which guarantees the equivalence of the first $N$ moments.

---

Also, note that there are infinitely many possible choices of $G$. A particularly convenient choice is a mixture distribution. An $N$-mixture-of-normal should provide more than enough degree of freedom to match the first $N$ moments of $X$. This should also generalize to $\mathbb{R}^n$ when considering mixture of Gaussian vectors.

Comment: I suppose I should have been more specific in my question. Given a specific $Y$, computing $f$ is straightforward using a Knothe-Rosenblatt rearrangement, which reduces to a copula transform in 1D. My question if more about $f$ itself. What properties must it have to map $X$ to $Y$ and preserve the first $n$ moments and what might be a minimal/simple example if it exists?

Comment: Since given $Y$, $f$ is uniquely determined, I guess you can just exhaust all possible choices of $Y$. For example, you can approximate the distribution of any random variable by an appropriate mixture density (say, mixture-of-normal). Then $Y$ is simply the collection of all mixture-of-normals that satisfy the moment constraint, with $f$ being the corresponding collection of copula transforms.

Comment: $f$ is only unique in 1 dimension, but you are correct. It seems that this basically reduces to a measure transport problem with constraints given by the first $n$ moments, but I guess I was hoping there was something a bit more closed-form. Oh well